# Hosting for React / Redux / Node.js Web Application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, server, redux, web-hosting

I have written a simple web app with React / Redux / Nodejs, and it works on my system. What do I have to look out for now if i want to put this whole thing on a webserver? Are there any requirements or can I just grab a standard package from one of the standard hosting services, and I'm good to go?

Comment: Try looking at Heroku, RedHat OpenShift or Microsoft Azure

Comment: Thanks! So the answer as regards the standard hosting services is, no, i cannot use Hostgator / Bluehost etc. as easily?

Comment: The hosting provider should make it clear to you if they can support hosting.

You need a hosting solution that supports node applications and serving static files.

If you have dedicated/VPS/cloud hosting then you can install node yourself. If you're on a shared hosting service, then the hosting provider should support node (they typically make it clear on their site/docs/support).